# Make sure pandas read_csv obeys given dtypes

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following csv data, `data.csv`. It should be noted that the csv-file is properly formatted, and does not contain any 'weird' stuff.

```
id,date,time,name,value,description
0,2017-01-07,2017-01-07 11:49:29,cool_name1,2,something
1,2017-01-07,2017-01-07 11:51:50,cool_name1,-1,something
2,2017-01-07,2017-01-07 14:03:42,cool_name2,9,something
```

I read it in via:

```
schema = {'id': float,
          'date': str,
          'time': str,
          'name': str,
          'value': float,
          'description': str}
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=0, dtype=schema,
                 parse_dates=['date', 'time'])
```

which results in `df.dtypes`:

```
id           int64
date         datetime64[ns]
time         datetime64[ns]
name         object
value        float64
description  object
```

Due to where the data is going, `id` has to be auto-parsed as specified by `schema` (`float` in this case). However, after trying a bunch of different keyword arguments in combination with each other, I can't get `id` to obey my `dtype`.

List of what I have tried:

```
dtype=schema
converters=schema
low_memory=False
engine='c' AND 'python'
index_col=False
parse_dates=False
```

It should be noted that the column `value` does obey `dtype`, and without it specified it becomes `int64`.

What is the missing ingredient (pandas version 0.23.4)?

Comment: This works fine for me in version `0.23.3`

Comment: Works fine for me in version `0.23.4` too

Comment: Now that is weird, I am running python 3.7 btw. After re-installing pandas, I still have the same bad behaviour :(